# WordPress tag mass delete using MYSQL

Tags: wordpress

I want to delete mass delete tags(infect I want to delete all tags) from my WordPress database. Can somebody help me with the MySQL query?

Comment: How many tags do you have and have you tried anything yourself yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably back up your db first, and then I believe you want:

```
delete from wp_term_relationships where term_taxonomy_id in(
  select term_taxonomy_id from wp_term_taxonomy where taxonomy='post_tag'
);
```